# search button load gridview after c# asp.net 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, .net-2.0

When i click the search button,load the Gridview.At that GridView,i can add,delete and update. When the user click add , the message box pop up "Customer added successfuly"
Then i have to click " SearchButton" again.If not i cant see the GridView again.
Cause i just wirte the code to load the Gridview by clicking the Searchbutton. How can I fix it?
For the Very first time, I just have some dropdownlist and Search button only. Please help me. Thanks

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //Check if Add button clicked
        if (e.CommandName == "AddProject")
        {
            try
            {
                //Get the values stored in the text boxes


                string strProjectName = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPJDESCLONG")).Text;
                string strLastUpdate = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtLASTUPDATE")).Text;
                string strStatus = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtSTATUS")).Text;
                string strUsername = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtUSERNAME")).Text;
                string strProjCode = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPJCODE")).Text;


               //Prepare the Insert Command of the DataSource control

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
                string strSQL = "";


                 if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) { conn.Open(); }

                 strSQL = "INSERT INTO  CTORGPROJ (CTPAPBRCH,CTPAPDIV,CTPAPDEPT,CTPAPSECT,CTPAPSSEC,CTPAPPDIV,CTPAPLOC,CTPAPPDEP,PJCODE,PJDESCLONG,LASTUPDATE,STATUS, " +
                 "USERNAME)  VALUES ('" + cboBranch.SelectedValue + "','" + cboDivision.SelectedValue + "','" + cboDepartment.SelectedValue + "','" + cboSection.SelectedValue + "','" + cboSubSection.SelectedValue + "','" + cboLocation.SelectedValue + "','" + cboPayDivision.SelectedValue + "','" + cboPayDepartment.SelectedValue + "','" + strProjCode + "','" + strProjectName + "','" +
                 strLastUpdate + "','" + strStatus + "','" + strUsername + "')";

                 Session.Add("conn", CookieUtil.GetTripleDESEncryptedCookieValue("sConn").Replace("-", ";"));
            Session.Add("PjNo", CookieUtil.GetTripleDESEncryptedCookieValue("sPjCode"));
            Session.Add("sComCode", CookieUtil.GetTripleDESEncryptedCookieValue("sComCode"));

            string _strConn = Session["conn"].ToString();
            _strConn = _strConn.Replace("Provider=SQLOLEDB;", "");

            SqlDataSource SqlDataSource1 = new SqlDataSource(_strConn, strSQL);


                        SqlDataSource1.InsertCommand = strSQL;
                        SqlDataSource1.Insert();

                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Message", "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>alert('Customer added successfully');</script>");

                        GridView1.DataBind();

                        conn.Close();
                        conn.Dispose();

                 }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Message", "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>alert('" + ex.Message.ToString().Replace("'", "") + "');</script>");

                    }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a flag in a view-state to decide if grid view to be shown or not. Initial value will be false.
2. Have a method say `ShowGrid` that will add (if needed) your grid, bind the data and make it visible.
3. On click of search, set the view-state flag true and call `ShowGrid` method.
4. In `Page_Load` event, check if the view-state flag is true (in post-back condition) and if true then call `ShowGrid` method.